# Not able to instantiate neo4j

Tags: spring, nosql, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm starting to learn the neo4j DB. My test code is below:

```
@Test
public void persistedMovieShouldBeRetrievableFromGraphDb() {
    GraphDatabaseService graphDB = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("data/graph.db");
    registerShutdownHook(graphDB);
    Transaction tx = graphDB.beginTx();
    try{
        Neo4jTemplate template = new Neo4jTemplate(graphDB);
        Movie forrestGump = template.save(new Movie("Forrest Gump", 1994));
        Movie retrievedMovie = template.findOne(forrestGump.getId(), Movie.class);
        assertEquals("Retrieved Movie matched persisted one", forrestGump, retrievedMovie);
        assertEquals("retrieved movie title matches", "Forrest Gump", retrievedMovie.getTitle());
    }
    finally{
        tx.finish();
    }
}
```

However, it always gives an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.SpringTransactionManager.<init>(Lorg/neo4j/kernel/GraphDatabaseAPI;)V
```

Comment: I've seen this problem. In your `pom.xml` you have neo4j declared and spring-data-neo4j, correct?

Comment: @Nicholas I don't have a pom.xml. I'm managing my JARs manually.

Comment: Well can you tell us which JAR's you have for spring-data-neo4j and neo4j-kernel?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nicholas' suggestion that this is most likely a simply pom.xml configuration problem. Take a look at the sample Spring Data Neo4j [example projects](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples) to compare the declared dependencies with your project.

-Andreas